# 2 monitors + HDMI LCD Screen 

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I currently have an nVidia GTX 480, with two DVI ports and one HDMI. I have the two DVIs plugged into 1680x1050 resolution monitors and the HDMI into a 1080p HD TV.

Currently Windows7's screen resolution tool will only let me have one monitor + TV or 2 monitors and no TV showing extended desktops at a time. Is this a software or hardware limitation?

If I get better multi-monitor software will I be able to extend my desktop across all three screens?

Comment: I believe most cards have the HDMI port sharing with a DVI port, making it a hardware limitation. You could consider buying a cheap additional GPU and using that for your extra monitor.

Comment: I think he was hoping for something like ATI's Eyefinity which itself is a hardware modification. . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect 3 monitors, but one will be disabled. The point of having the 3 ports is to give you options, so you can choose between using DVI or HDMI. Here's a quote from [a thread on the NVIDIA forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?s=90b89836e9c8c285594c4f6a8a087858&showtopic=169320&view=findpost&p=1066010) when someone asked about multiple monitors on the GTX 480

> For graphics cards which have a single GPU onboard like the Geforce
>   GTX 480 or 470, only two displays can be active at the same time even
>   if the card has three physical monitor connectors. Some cards like the
>   older version of the Geforce GTX 295 have two GPUs onboard and three
>   display connections, two DVI and one HDMI. The first two ports, the
>   two DVI ports are connected to the first GPU and the HDMI port is
>   connected to the 2nd GPU. So in this case, three monitors could be
>   supported as long as the card wasn't set to "multi-GPU" mode. But for
>   pretty much every NVIDIA graphics card, you will only be able to
>   activate two monitors at the same time.

This is a hardware limitation. I suggest purchasing a cheaper card like a GT 220 and putting that in to add more monitors.